# How to split Heat map at specific rows in R

Tags: r, split

I have made a heatmap in R, which I have made from a large dataframe (1522 columns X 26 rows). I want to split the heatmap into 5 horizontal sections at rows 7, 11, 16 and 21.

I have tried the following code but it does not work.

```
df <- read.csv("/home/Ahm/gene.csv")
View(df)

df1<- t(df[,2:ncol(df)])
colnames(df1) <- df[,1]
View (df1)
df2 <- scale(df1)

library(ComplexHeatmap)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(circlize)
mycols <- colorRamp2(breaks = c(0, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.6, 1.0), 
                     colors = c('yellow', 'pink', "orange", "red", "black", "blue"))

png("/home/aahm/Desktop/test.png",width=16,height=8,units="cm", res=100)
Heatmap(df1, width = unit(10, "cm"), height = unit(5, "cm"),
        name = "site PI values",
        row_names_gp = gpar(fontsize = 5.5), column_title = "Nucleotide Positions", row_title = '1000 Genomes populations',
        column_title_side = "bottom",
        col = mycols,
        show_column_dend = FALSE, cluster_rows = FALSE,
        column_order = order(as.numeric(gsub("column", "", colnames(df1)))),
        column_names_rot = 45,
        row_split = data.frame(rep(c("A", "B","C","D","E"), 7, 11, 15, 21, 26))
)

dev.off()
```

I am having the following error:
Error: Length or nrow of `row_split` should be same as nrow of `matrix`.

I tried some other ways of doing this but nothing works. Can somebody help me out please?

Comment: you should examine the object you are passing to `row_split` to see if it makes sense

Comment: @rawr. I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: If I do the following: row_split = data.frame(rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), 7,4,5,5,5)), it still does not work. But If I split into 2 horizontal sections as follows: row_split = data.frame(rep(c("A", "B"), 13)), it works.

Comment: just type `data.frame(rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), 7,4,5,5,5))` into your console and see what it looks like

Comment: I tried it. Didn't work

Answer (score 1):

I simply had to create a variable containing the number of rows for each horizontal section. Here goes the coding:

```
row.subsections <- c(7,4,5,5,5)
row_split = data.frame(rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), row.subsections)).
```